# Shell Scripting problem

Tags: shell, unix

So I am new to this shell scripting stuff and I got a task set to me to create a shell script which takes in two files, and compares them with each other (similar to the diff command) except you cannot use diff.

I am completely stuck and have no idea how to even attempt this problem.

EDIT: sorry, I can only use nl, join and sort

Comment: task == homework? ^^ Moreover: what is supposed to output this newly invented `diff`?

Comment: ln -s /usr/bin/diff myscript.sh

Comment: yeah it's homework

if you take two files, e.g. file1 file2 it will give you the longest common subsequence

Answer (score 0):

[use comm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)

comm compares 2 files line by line and supports different output schemes (only uniques to a file, only common lines, etc)